# Android NDK: Linking "error: undefined reference to" GLES functions

Tags: android-ndk

So I have the following on my Android.mk....

```
...
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include /Users/myname/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include
...
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -lGLESv1_CM -llog
```

However, when I try running ndk-build I get the following....

> /Users/myname/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/libSDL.a(SDL_render_gles.o): in function GLES_CreateRenderer:jni/SDL/src/render/opengles/SDL_render_gles.c:189: error: undefined reference to 'glDisableClientState'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

This of course appears to be an issue linking, however, the compiler worked just fine. I am confused as to why the linking wouldn't work but the compilation would. Anyonw know how I could fix it?

From ndk-build V=1 >Build.log [Output](http://www.speedyshare.com/F5Ebe/build.log)

UPDATE:

Ok so I am taking the code found [here](https://code.google.com/p/prboom4android/source/browse/#svn/trunk/jni/prboom) this compiles fine, however, I am trying to upgrade to PRBoom+ so I dl the code from [here](https://www.crowproductions.de/repos/prboom/branches/prboom-plus-24/prboom2/src/) and tweak the Android.mk to include the new classes. Once this is done it seems to compile fine, however, it fails to properly link. There are two main errors I see...

First is involving multiple definitions, however, the original (compiled linked fine) code had the same multiple definitions....

> /Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/prboom_jni/w_mmap.o: multiple definition of 'W_InitCache'

The other type is the OpenGL issues...

> /Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/libSDL.a(SDL_render_gles.o): in function GLES_ResetState:/Users/jackiegleason/Development/Code/prboom4android-base/jni/SDL/src/render/opengles/SDL_render_gles.c:181: error: undefined reference to 'glDisable'

If I copy everything back (using the prboom4android code) everything compiles and links just fine.

Here is a diff of the 2 Android.mk files...

```
< LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH) $(LOCAL_PATH)/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../SDL_net/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../SDL/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/MUSIC $(LOCAL_PATH)/MUSIC/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/TEXTSCREEN $(LOCAL_PATH)/TEXTSCREEN/include
---
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH) $(LOCAL_PATH)/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../SDL_net/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../SDL/include
28c28
<   f_finale.c p_enemy.c p_spec.c r_plane.c w_mmap.c i_capture.c \
---
>   f_finale.c p_enemy.c p_spec.c r_plane.c w_mmap.c \
31,36c31,33
<   m_bbox.c p_inter.c p_tick.c r_things.c z_zone.c s_advsound.c memio.c \
<   d_client.c i_video.c i_network.c i_system.c PCSOUND/pcsound.c PCSOUND/pcsound_sdl.c SDL/i_sshot.c \
<   i_main.c sc_man.c SDL/i_sound.c jni_doom.c mus2mid.c pcm2wav.c e6y.c SDL/i_joy.c \
<         r_screenmultiply.c hu_tracers.c i_smp.c g_overflow.c i_pcsound.c \
<         MUSIC/dbopl.c MUSIC/flplayer.c MUSIC/portmidiplayer.c MUSIC/midifile.c MUSIC/opl_queue.c MUSIC/vorbisplayer.c MUSIC/dumbplayer.c MUSIC/oplplayer.c MUSIC/madplayer.c MUSIC/opl.c \
<         TEXTSCREEN/txt_button.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_separator.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_gui.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_widget.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_checkbox.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_radiobutton.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_inputbox.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_spinctrl.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_window.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_desktop.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_scrollpane.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_io.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_strut.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_window_action.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_dropdown.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_sdl.c TEXTSCREEN/txt_label.c  TEXTSCREEN/txt_table.c 
---
>   m_bbox.c p_inter.c p_tick.c r_things.c z_zone.c \
>   d_client.c i_video.c i_network.c i_system.c \
>   i_main.c i_sound.c jni_doom.c mmus2mid.c pcm2wav.c
```

Comment: Please run `ndk-build V=1` and post the build log. It will be easy to answer your question when we see your compilation and link parameters.

Comment: Sounds good I can do that, however, what is the best way to post it? Should I host the log somewhere or embed it in the question?

Comment: Let me know if that file doesn't work, I have never used that site before

Comment: regarding `W_InitCache`: simply grep for this symbol in your extended project.

Comment: regarding `glDisable`: simply switch from `-lGLESv1_CM` to `-lGLESv2`

Comment: Alex I know where the W_InitCache cache is I just need this to be ignored. It seems to ignore it in the existing code because it is still in both places. The switching the GL to v2 shouldn't matter because 1.1 has those same methods (search for GLES/gl.h). Thanks for sticking with this though maybe we will find it yet....

Comment: GCC linker does not ignore multiple references, the makefile should choose only one compilation unit that defines each reference. Does the next line say "first defined here"? You are right, GLESv1_CM.so is OK -- but not for __android-3__

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I could download your [Build.log](http://www19.speedyshare.com/F5Ebe/download/build.log).

Your build uses `APP_PLATFORM = android-3`, which does not have the necessary GL libraries. You can set `APP_PLATFORM = android-14` in your **Application.mk**, or set the target platform for your Android project (Eclipse will update the **project.properties** file).

You should not add the android-14 includes manually in your **Android.mk**. When you have correct **APP_PLATFORM**, the include path will be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Ok so I tried that, and although that may have been an issue it doesn't solve the problem. I will add more details to the main desc in a minute that may help.

Comment: ps, I am not really using eclipse

Comment: Eclipse may only create the project.properties file; if you set APP_PLATFORM in Application.mk, it does not matter at all.